# which among the anchor tags with the same class was clicked? get its id

Tags: javascript, html

I have a few anchor tags with the same class.

```
<a href='' id='id1' class='abc'>Link 1</a>
<a href='' id='id2' class='abc'>Link 2</a>
<a href='' id='id3' class='abc'>Link 3</a>
```

I want to know which among these anchor tag was clicked and then get its id.
This should be done using javascript (not jquery). Please help.
Again, no jquery.

Comment: Again, what you've tried?

Comment: I tried in jquery and it worked :                                   $(document).ready(function () {
  $('.abc').click(function (event) {

    var hr = $(this).attr("id");
    alert(hr);
  });
 });                                                                                                                           Was trying the same in javascript with getElementsByClassName but had no luck.

Answer (score 1):

Try this , tested and works 100%

```
    <a href='#' id='id1' class='abc'>Link 1</a>
    <a href='#' id='id2' class='abc'>Link 2</a>
    <a href='#' id='id3' class='abc'>Link 3</a>

    <script>
        var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("abc");
        for(var i = 0, len = elements.length; i < len; i++) {
            elements[i].onclick = function () {
                alert(this.id);
            }
        }
    </script>
```

Comment: Sorry, but I don't want to use onclick in tags. HTML should be left as it is. Solution should be reached with javascript.

Comment: @SumeetKumar... check my updated answer... please please vote up if you are happy with my answer :) tested and works 100%..thanks

Answer (score 1):

Since you have same class for all three anchor tags`<a>`, you can bind event listeners to elements with class `abc`.

```css
var ele=document.getElementsByClassName('abc') for(var i=0;
i<ele.length;
i++) {
  ele[i].addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    alert(e.target.id)
  }
  , false);
}
```

```html
<a href='#' id='id1' class='abc'>Link 1</a>
<a href='#' id='id2' class='abc'>Link 2</a>
<a href='#' id='id3' class='abc'>Link 3</a>
```

`getElementsByClassName` returns an array of the elements matching the criteria.

**Note:** Older browsers (like IE6, IE7, IE8) don´t support getElementsByClassName and so they return undefined.

Answer (score 0):

```
Please check link active link on click link
```

https://jsfiddle.net/Sunildalal/aLw2op3m/